# How to use a local API with a Vue app served at a different port?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm helping someone get a Django + Vue app up and running and one issue we're running into is how to have the Vue app hot-reload while also being able to interact with the local Django server.

In production the Django server will serve the Vue app, and `npm run build` puts the Vue app's assets in the Django project's `templates/` and `static/` folders.

When we run the Django server (`python manage.py runserver`), the server is running at `localhost:8000`.  When we run `npm run serve` (to get the benefits of hot reloading), the Vue app is being served at `localhost:8080`.  If I do a GET request from the Vue app to `/exampleEndpoint`, it goes to `localhost:8080/exampleEndpoint`, thus not hitting the Django server.

What's the proper way to have the Vue app work with the Django app?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It is hard to offer any help without code and stack trace

Comment: @MikeTung This is for a Django + Webpacked vue-cli project, it seems to me that a minimal example would involve dozens of files.  If something I wrote is not clear, let me know.

Comment: Ok... how do you expect us to know what calls you make and if it is a syntax error, config error, or just a file completely missing?

Comment: Make a request to `:8000/exampleEndpoint` when developing or even better serve both behind nginx and have nginx route the requests to the correct process

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you, do you know how I can have the port vary based on a configuration / environment variable?

Comment: Why do you want to use Django to serve the Vue app in the first place? You could follow the very basic principle of splitting backend & frontend completely. Serve Django as usual and Vue with e. g. Express via Node, use a RESTful API in Django to make the data available for consuming by Vue (e. g. via Axios).

Comment: @BennettDams The person I'm helping wanted to do it that way, but it may be worth bringing it up again at this point.

Comment: @NathanWailes If you put time and effort into something, do it right. Using Django to serve a Vue SPA is like attaching a steering wheel on top of a car to steer the steering wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using axios then you can do:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = '//localhost:8000/';
```

Omitting http/s and just starting with double slash will make the current protocol be inherited into the url.

This will result in `axios.post('/api/example')` requesting http(s)://localhost:8000/api/example as long as all your request URI's start with a single slash.

Edit: You will need to allow CORS Headers. There is a package `django-cors-headers` for this. It's very easy to use and works just fine: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/

Comment: You can also configure a devserver-proxy in `vue.config.js` to prevent cross origin resource sharing (CORS) issues https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Comment: but you have not mentioned where to put this line 'axios.defaults.baseURL = '//localhost:8000/'' ?? this is an incomplete answer

Comment: @NitinNanda there is no one answer to this in reguards to where do i put this, depends on how you are implementing axios, if you are using script includes, es6 imports or multiple instances those factors are going to change where you need to put it...
This answer points you in the direction of the setting you need may need to address a base URL issue not how to implement it, where you put it is down to you to figure out for your particular use case or ask a separate question on how to use it for your use case.

Answer (score -2):

The solution we ended up going with (which isn't really answering this question's title but solves the underlying problem) was to not use the vue-cli hot reload server but rather have changes to the front-end's files trigger `npm run build`, so that the front-end app would be served by the Django server (as it would be in production).  To accomplish this I installed the "npm-watch" package and have "npm run watch" watch all .vue, .scss, and .js files in the `/src` directory.  The commit is below.

[image]

Comment: The appropriate way to do this is IMO to do as @thibautg said, use a [proxy](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy).